# best_in_place inline error in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin

I have need to change boolean field directly inline from index, without passing from edit page.

I get this error in activeadmin when I put gem best_in_place in index:

undefined method `event' for #

Here my code:

```
column :active do |billboard|
      best_in_place billboard,
                :active,
                as: :checkbox,
                path: [:admin, billboard.event, billboard],
                collection: %w[HIDE SHOW]
```

here my entire code:

```
  index do
    column :name
    column :description
    column :active
    column :attempts_number
    column :finished
    column :created_at
    # gem best_in_place
    column :active do |billboard|
      best_in_place billboard,
                :active,
                as: :checkbox,
                path: [:admin, billboard.event, billboard],
                collection: %w[HIDE SHOW]
    end
    actions
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your code is inside

```
index do
 ... your code here ...
end
```

then you will get your expected result in your index page itself

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have check and was already inside index do, take a look I have update my question adding all code.